# How can I embed font in Visual Basic .Net application?

Tags: vb.net, fonts

How can I embed font in Visual Basic .Net application? which should valid at every operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to embed a font in an application and use it if that font is not available on the user's system.

You simply create a [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) and populate it with your fonts then you can use them as you please. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile.aspx), this method does not apply to operating systems before Windows 2000.

> From **Remarks** section of [PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile.aspx) method:
>
> > *When using a private font on operating systems before Windows 2000, the default font, typically Microsoft Sans Serif, will be substituted.*

If you intend your application to be used on Windows 2000 and newer, you can follow this code I wrote to see how to implement private fonts.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim pfc As System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
    Dim ifc As System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        pfc = New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
        ifc = New System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection()

        LoadPrivateFonts({My.Resources.Series_60_ZDigi, My.Resources.Times_NR_Phonetics_2})
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>Loads the private fonts.</summary>
    ''' <param name="fonts">The fonts to be loaded into the private font collection.</param>
    Private Sub LoadPrivateFonts(ByVal fonts As IEnumerable(Of Byte()))
        For Each resFont In fonts
            pfc.AddMemoryFont(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(resFont, 0), resFont.Length)
        Next
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>Gets the FontFamily whose name matches the one specified.</summary>
    ''' <param name="fontName">Name of the FontFamily to be returned.</param>
    ''' <param name="defaultFamily">
    ''' Optional. The default font family to be returned if the specified font is not found
    ''' </param>
    Private Function GetFontFamily(ByVal fontName As String, Optional ByVal defaultFamily As FontFamily = Nothing) As FontFamily
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(fontName) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("fontName", "The name of the font cannont be null.")
        End If

        Dim foundFonts = From font In ifc.Families.Union(pfc.Families) Where font.Name.ToLower() = fontName.ToLower()

        If foundFonts.Any() Then
            Return foundFonts.First()
        Else
            Return If(defaultFamily, FontFamily.GenericSansSerif)
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Disposed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
        'free the resources used by the font collections
        pfc.Dispose()
        ifc.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim g = e.Graphics

        Using br As Brush = Brushes.Black
            g.DrawString("1234567890ABCDEF", New Font(GetFontFamily("Series 60 ZDigi"), 18), br, New Point(20, 20))
            g.DrawString("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", New Font(GetFontFamily("Times NR Phonetics 2"), 18), br, New Point(20, 100))
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I load the two fonts I use in the application (Series 60 ZDigi, a font from my Nokia phone, and Times NR Phonetics 2, a font from my dictionary application) from the resources into the private font collection in the `Sub New()`.
I then call the `GetFontFamily` method to get the desired font to paint onto the form.

It shouldn't be too hard to incorporate this into your applications.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.** There is no cross-platform standard at this point for embedded fonts in a standard Winforms application. The best you can do is embed individual, OS-specific font files, detect which OS you're on, and then install the font programmatically.

On the other hand, A WPF application in VB.net might work for your needs, but I have a feeling this isn't where you're going. For information on how to package fonts with a WPF application, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx).

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble but **It Can Be Done**. It just may not work on all operating systems but it does work on Win2k onwards. See my answer for how it is done.