# vb.net, how to override users desktop font settings

Tags: .net, vb.net

This seems like a dumb question, but i have looked ALL over and couldn't find an answer.

My problem is when i create a Simple VB.NET WinForm, with say a couple txtBoxes and Labels, then i goto test my .exe on another computer, and the user has some crazy script font thats like 36px and my program seems to inherit HIS font settings, not the ones i set.

Then when i open my program i see his crazy script font in the textboxes, and his font is so big you cant even read it...

How can i make my app NOT inherit Font or color scheme from the user ?? but what I set ??

I'm using Win7 x64, but i need this fix for XP to Win8

Comment: Are you setting the font in your Form

Comment: YES, i am setting ALL properties of the font before compile.

Comment: Is the font you are using present on the client computer

Comment: Is this a VB.NET or VB6 application?

Comment: YES, i am just using VERDANA, it's common pretty much everywhere, **BUT** his crazy script font takes over, i dont want that, i want the font I SET to be THE font.. and i am using VB.NET, but i am also using  VB6, is there any easy way to implement for both ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links could help you ..

[How can I embed font in Visual Basic .Net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027963/how-can-i-embed-font-in-visual-basic-net-application)

http://zerosandtheone.com/blogs/vb/archive/2009/11/20/vb-net-include-a-font-as-an-embedded-resource-in-your-application.aspx