# Embed a font in an application

Tags: .net, vb.net, fonts, visual-studio-2013

I've created a `Windows Forms Application` in `.Net 4.0` on Windows 8.1.

Tinkering with the fonts, I've selected `Microsoft Sans Serif` for some of the UI. On older machines (Windows 7) this is displayed incorrectly as they do not have the font.

Is there a way to embed the font I've selected in the application?

Doing some research shows Microsoft articles on how to do this in Blend, but I'm not using that.

Comment: `MS Sans Serif` goes back to Win 3.1 and is the default form font in VB.NET.  If it is not displaying correctly, it is not likely for that reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027963/how-can-i-embed-font-in-visual-basic-net-application ? maybe