# Adding multiple external fonts to my winform application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, fonts, external

I would like to add or deploy the app with more than 10 external fonts from my resource folder. I have gone through various SO questions but none of them suits my requirement except this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027963/how-can-i-embed-font-in-visual-basic-net-application).

Now I have implemeted the same thing in my winform app and I would like to add these fonts to combo box with their styles such as shown below.

[image]

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: So to clarify, you have embedded the fonts into your application, but you aren't sure how to add them to a `ComboBox` and have them render in their respective fonts?

Comment: @Anthony- Exactly thats what I would like to know..I have seen it for a single font but would like to know for multiple fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the items in the `ComboBox` yourself if you want to show them in the drop down in their appropriate font. This isn't hard, the following code does the bare minimum:

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox.Items.AddRange(FontFamily.Families);
comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
comboBox.DrawItem += (s, e) => {

    var fontFamily = (FontFamily) comboBox.Items[e.Index];
    var itemText = comboBox.GetItemText(fontFamily);

    // Some fonts don't work with a regular style, if they don't have a
    // regular style, we'll default to the provided font.
    if (!fontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(
            e.Graphics, itemText, e.Font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var font = new Font(fontFamily, comboBox.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular))
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(
                e.Graphics, itemText, font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor,
                TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left);
        }
    }

};
```

This implementation handles a `FontFamily` not having a regular font style by falling back to the `ComboBox`'s default font. You can handle this more gracefully by attempting to find a valid style for the `FontFamily` before creating the font.